# Multiple rows container view to layout children based on their width

Tags: ios, objective-c, custom-controls

Basically I'm trying to find an iOS library (Obj-C is preferred) for a custom view described below. I wasn't able to find something similar but still it looks like this is pretty common view so maybe anybody from the community can point me to the right place.

So I'm trying to implement a view in iOS to replicate behavior from the image:

[image]

Basically it's a horizontal container view which stacks other views (basically UILabels) based on their width and dynamically adds more rows when required.

So my current approach on a high level is to implement it as the following:

1. to pass a list of NSStrings into the container view
2. container view will create UILabels for every string
3. It then calculates width for every label and total widths of all labels
4. container view dynamically calculates number of items for the current row based on container's width.
5. The rest items comes to the next row (container height increases) and step 4 repeats while there are unprocessed UILabels in the queue.

While the process is rather straightforward I'm still trying to find possible ways to simplify the development and to save client's budget on this feature.

So maybe someone can point a better approach? Seems like UICollectionView can be a good alternative but still maybe there are any libraries which do something similar to what I've described above?

Couldn't find anything on github but probably it's just because I'm searching it incorrectly.

Comment: UICollectionView is the vest approach as per you are thinking.As same ditto sample is already developed by me, even more dynamic then your requiment so as per experience it is easy to build and manage. You can take 3rd party too.

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy thanks for your comment. Yeah, UICollectionView probably fits much better than manual approach. Anyway do you have any links to 3rd party libs to check?

Comment: You can use https://github.com/mokagio/UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout

Comment: I found out some on github, hope this two helps you. [1. Gupta](https://github.com/riteshhgupta/TagCellLayout) [2. keight](https://github.com/keighl/KTCenterFlowLayout). Soon I will update mine project too.

Comment: @SahanaKini thanks for the link - it's definitely helpful

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy - thanks a lot for posting, will save it for future reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code work**

```
    - (IBAction)actionTagCancel:(UIButton *)sender {
    [arrTagList removeObjectAtIndex:sender.tag];
    [self.collecTagCategory reloadData];

}


#pragma mark- collection data source

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return arrTagList.count;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    CGSize tagLabelSize = [arrTagList[indexPath.row] boundingRectWithSize: CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width-75, 120)
                                                              options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                           attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:14.0 ]}
                                                              context:nil].size;

    return CGSizeMake (tagLabelSize.width + 45, 30);
}

- (__kindof UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    TagViewListCell *tagCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"tagCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    tagCell.viewTag.layer.cornerRadius = 4;

    tagCell.btnTagCancel.tag = indexPath.row;

    tagCell.lblTagName.text = arrTagList[indexPath.row];
    _constTagViewHeight.constant = _collecTagCategory.contentSize.height;
    return tagCell;

}
```

**Output**

[image]

Automatic manageable after deletion of tag

[image]

> Edit

[Get Repository of project from here](https://github.com/thedahiyaboy/TDTagIndex)

Comment: thanks for sharing this - exactly what I was looking for!